# How to use std::round in android ndk

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, cmake

I am trying to build a `c++` library using `android ndk` and `android studio`. I am using `CMakeList` to define the different flags.

```
        cmake {
           cppFlags "-std=c++11 -frtti -fexceptions -v -Wall -Werror -Wno-unused-variable -w"
           abiFilters 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'mips', 'mips64'
        }
```

I have some `c++ 11` functions in the library. I would like to know how can I build that ?

I am getting the following error.

```
error: no member named 'round' in namespace 'std'
```

How can I fix it ?

Comment: #include <math.h>

Comment: @user1438832 It doesn't work. I have also tried cmath. both doesn't work.

Comment: Which STL implementation are you linking against? If it's stlport I'd suggest switching to gnustl or libc++, which both should have `std::round`.

Comment: @Michael I am trying to build it against `dlib` http://dlib.net/
How can I switch to  `gnustl` or `libc++`?

Comment: Set the `APP_STL` variable in your Application.mk to [the appropriate value](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html#runtimes).

Comment: For CMake you'll need to set ANDROID_STL in your gradle file: `cmake { arguments "gnustl_shared" }`: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cmake.html